# IDA Pro remote automation

Tags: python, automation, remote-access, ida

I am trying to run IDA Pro (full version) remotely through a linux terminal as to automate the analysis and output process. I know there are plugins such as IDAPython and there is the use of the flags for terminals using the idal command. My question is whether or not it is possible to write a script in either IDAscript or IDApython that can:

1.) Start the IDA Pro process

2.) Pass it a file(s) to perform analysis on

3.) Output this file into an .html format (or .txt)

4.) all without any user interaction besides determining which files to send it and initializing the script.

IN FURTHER DETAIL: How can I pass IDA the file I am trying to analyse via command line flag that accompanies what I have been trying (idal -A). Is there a flag to output the info into a .html file I am not seeing? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: To expand on my first comment and more particular to what you are trying - you can always simply call remote /cmd or /shell commands. As long as IDA can be run via a command line interface you can run it remotely.

Comment: Yes I understand that by using the idal command via linux terminal I can call upon a version that will work throughout my terminal and present a somewhat tangible interface. I suppose in more detail I am trying to get this automated. My question would then be, how can I pass IDA the file (I am trying to analyse via IDA) via command line (is there a flag I am not seeing). Is there a flag to output the info into a .html file I am not seeing?

Comment: This seems less a programming problem and more an IDA problem, you should probably consult IDA documentation or ask on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Thank You for your feedback Inbar Rose, I will try to provide more explanatory questions in the future.

Comment: I thought that at first as well, however, after reading through the IDA Book it would seem there is no Ida flag. Instead it would need to be done throughout IDAPython script, which is where I need the help but I will definitely check out superuser.se.

Answer (score 0):

Ida command line arguments: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml

Make a python server, that gets on a socket (1) file to analyze (2) name of script to run

Then , on the server run ida with subprocess.
Pass a a script for ida to run with -S flag (you can also pass a few arguments for the acript, see in the link)

Make the script save to output so some file, and once subprocess is done send the file back to the user.